# Движение прямоугольника по форме

Tags: java, javafx, анимация

Приветствую!
Как сделать средвами javaFX перемещение прямоугольника?

вот код:
main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

controller.java

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
Rectangle tube = new Rectangle();


public void onClick() throws InterruptedException {
    int x = 0;
    while(x < 100){
        Double a = tube.getX();
        Double b = tube.getY();
        tube.setX(a-5);
        x++;
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }

}


}
```

Пример формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы этот прямоугольник ехал до конца линейки влево. Как сделать это?

UPD1::

```
public void onClick() throws InterruptedException {

   takeFrom();

    // Конечная позиция:
    double stopPositionX = 24;

    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
            // Считаем, сколько времени будет длиться анимация:
            Duration.millis((tube.getLayoutX() - stopPositionX) / 5 * 10),

            event -> {
                System.out.println("Перемещение трубы по отводящему рольгангу окончено");
            },

            // Указываем, какое свойство анимировать, его конечное значение и алгоритм:
            new KeyValue(tube.layoutXProperty(), stopPositionX, Interpolator.LINEAR)
    );

    // Создаем и запускаем одноразовый таймер для анимации по ключевому кадру:
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.play();

}

public void takeFrom(){

    // Конечная позиция:
    double stopPositionY = 216;

    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
            // Считаем, сколько времени будет длиться анимация:
            Duration.millis((tube.getLayoutY() - stopPositionY) / 2 * 10),

            event -> {
                System.out.println("Движение закончено");
            },

            // Указываем, какое свойство анимировать, его конечное значение и алгоритм:
            new KeyValue(tube.layoutYProperty(), stopPositionY, Interpolator.LINEAR)
    );

    // Создаем и запускаем одноразовый таймер для анимации по ключевому кадру:
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.play();

}
```

Comment: Не забудьте использовать `Math.abs()` для времени — иначе получите исключение при отрицательном результате (в примере подправил).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант:

```
public void onClick() {
    // Конечная позиция:
    double stopPositionX = 100;

    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
            // Считаем, сколько времени будет длиться анимация:
            Duration.millis(Math.abs((tube.getLayoutX() - stopPositionX) / 5 * 10)),

            event -> {
                System.out.println("Анимация закончена");
            },

            // Указываем, какое свойство анимировать, его конечное значение и алгоритм:
            new KeyValue(tube.layoutXProperty(), stopPositionX, Interpolator.LINEAR)
    );

    // Создаем и запускаем одноразовый таймер для анимации по ключевому кадру:
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.play();
}
```

Поток JavaFX постоянно (60 раз в секунду) проверяет есть ли у него задания-таймеры и выполняет их.

И, конечно, это работает только в том случае, если никто не заблокировал поток JavaFX с помощью `Thread.sleep()`...

Ссылка на статью: 
[Creating Transitions and Timeline Animation in JavaFX: 1 Animation Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm)

---

*Дополнение к комментарию:*

Для последовательного выполнения анимаций используется `SequentialTransition`, например:

```
    KeyFrame keyFrame1 = new KeyFrame(...);
    Timeline timeline1 = new Timeline(keyFrame1);

    KeyFrame keyFrame2 = new KeyFrame(...);
    Timeline timeline2 = new Timeline(keyFrame2);

    SequentialTransition sequence = new SequentialTransition(timeline1, timeline2);
    sequence.play();
```

Comment: Работает, посмотрите пожалуйста апдейт? Мне нужно чтоб сначала фигура перемещалась по оси У а потом по оси Х

Comment: то есть мне нужно выполнить сначала один таймер потом другой